# Is it possible to run a 2GB RAM on Asrock G31M-VS?

Tags: windows-7, memory, cpu, motherboard

I just want to know if I can stick another 2GB RAM on my Computer.

System Hardware:

```
Motherboard: ASRock G31M-VS (FSB1333 DDR2 800 Dual Channel).
CPU: Pentium Dual-Core 2.5GHz.
RAM: DDR2 800
Memory: 2GB (1GB+1GB - I will remove one to add the 2GB RAM).
System type: 64-Bit Operating system - Windows Se7en Titan.
```

Comment: "Windows Se7en Titan" isn't an operating system from Microsoft.

Comment: It is an edited version of Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: By 'edited', do you mean 'pirated'?

Comment: No. I bought this from a trusted shop.

Comment: you shouldn't trust any shop which installed "Windows Se7en Titan". Up to you if you wish to report them to Microsoft, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The ASRock website (http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/G31M-VS/) for your motherboard states that it has TWO RAM slots for a system RAM total of 8GB.

> - Dual Channel DDR2 memory technology
> - 2 x DDR2 DIMM slots
> - Supports DDR2 800/667 non-ECC, un-buffered memory
> - Max. capacity of system memory: 8GB*

Comment: I know. But, is it possible to stick in 2GB RAM (like it will become 3GB)?

Comment: yes, but you will be running in Single channel mode then, and your RAM access will be slower. you'd be better off with 2x2gb chips.

Comment: So, I sticked in a 2GB RAM, but nothing happens, like there is no RAM sticked in.

Comment: Is the memory you're inserting compatible with the requirements of the motherboard?

Comment: I don't know, I'm just seeing "EC3 687", that looks interesting?

Comment: Where are you seeing this? You need to very precise with your questions/comments if you want a quicker answer!

Comment: There is no papers sticked in that RAM. I asked the seller yesterday and he says that my hardware doesn't support 2GB chipset, I didn't believed him for sure, but after this experience, he seems right.

Comment: Whoa re you going to believe, a seller or the board manufacturer? This is clearly either the wrong board or the memory isn't compatible with your board.